# Using different R lib in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, r, windows

I am working with a colleague who is learning QGIS and has a question about the R plugin. His library path (.libPaths()) has two folders:

```
"C:/Users/RDCERWAW/Documents/R/win-library/3.0" 
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.3/library"
```

When he downloads packages, they are downloaded to his personal library because the library in his Program Files folder is not writeable and he is unable to change permissions (dang Windows!). At any rate, everything works fine within R not run under QGIS, but when he is using R within QGIS, R is only trying to access packages in `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.3/library`. Since he can't write to this folder, the packages that he needs to run are not available.

Comment: You can change windows permissions for the library directory where packages are stored. In this way you do not need to use personal libraries or run R as administrator when installing packages.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up custom search path for your packages with function *.libPaths()* from *base*.

```
.libPaths("C:/Users/RDCERWAW/Documents/R/win-library/3.0")
```